# Deleting multiple blobs from Google Cloud Storage efficiently

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Deleting multiple blobs in a container is very slow when doing so one by one if the bucket contains a large amount of items.

```
public static void rmAll(Storage storage, String bucket) {
    Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucket, Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory());
    for(Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
        blob.delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can simply leverage [com.google.cloud.storage.StorageBatch](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-storage/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/StorageBatch.java) to efficiently delete multiple blobs in a bucket.

```
public static rmAll(Storage storage, String bucket) {
    StorageBatch batch = storage.batch();
    Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucket, Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory());
    for(Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
        batch.delete(blob.getBlobId());
    }
    batch.submit();
}
```

Comment: This answer is good. However, you need to limit the number of items in the batch delete. I don't remember the number but I think that it is 1,000.

Comment: @John, Perhaps this has been changed recently but I've ran this over a bucket containing over 5,000 items. I suspect it is my call to [`Page<Blob>.iterateAll()`](http://googleapis.github.io/gax-java/1.35.0/apidocs/com/google/api/gax/paging/Page.html#iterateAll--) as opposed to [`Page<Blob>.getValues()`](http://googleapis.github.io/gax-java/1.35.0/apidocs/com/google/api/gax/paging/Page.html#getValues--), though. `iterateAll()` is guaranteed to get all items in the underlying data source.

Comment: I will try to find this in the source code. It is not the `get`, but the `batch delete` that has the limit per API call. When I wrote a C++ SDK for Cloud Storage I ran into this. My memory is failing me on the exact details.

Comment: However, your answer is still correct. Just a small detail to get figured out for myself.

Comment: @John, if you figure out a limitation to my answer please get back to me so I can edit this for future Google searches. :)

Comment: Yes, I will. This is on my list of action items.

Comment: @MeetTitan 2 years later, but I made the research and the answer is that there is _no_ need to worry about batch size. First, there is no mention of that in the interface (it would be bad design on their side to have a hidden limit), but the implementation in fact does the "batching of batches" for us, see [source](https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage/blob/216b52c54d34eaf1307788809a3512c461adf381/google-cloud-storage/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/spi/v1/HttpStorageRpc.java#L132)